# Return Identity through Scalar Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a single Column table with ID column as Identity. I need to have a Function that can Insert and Return Newly inserted Identity on Function call. I have created a function but we cant use INSERT in SCALAR functions. What else could be a solution

Comment: What's the reason for needing a function over a statement/stored procedure?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. Not sure if SP could be a better option. Need any good advice / Suggestion

Comment: You can't use DML in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default function of sql server `Scope_Identity()` to get the newly inserted identity field. Please refer the link 
[SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)
for more details.

```
DECLARE @Identity INT
INSERT INTO TableName (Column1, Column2, )VALUES(@value1, @value2, ...)
SET @Identity=Scope_Identity()
```

You can make the same as stored procedure. Ex

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_ProcedureName
(
    @Input1 INT,
    @Identity INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableName (Col1) VALUES (@Input1)
    SET @Identity=Scope_Identity()
END
GO
```

Out put parameter can be retrieved by executing the stored procedure using `EXEC` command. Like

```
DECLARE @OutVar INT
EXEC USP_ProcedureName 1, @OutVar OUTPUT
SELECT @OutVar
```

Comment: Yes, but i want this inside a function/SP so that it can be called with just the name of fucntion/sp

Comment: You can do the same in SP. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: I want to use this value inside another Query as well. How can i do so. Can SP be called inside SQL Insert as a Paramter?

Comment: You can't use SP inside a query. But you can execute the procedure using `EXEC` command and retrieve the output value. Please check the edited answer.